# Install django on windows using Mercurial

Tags: windows, django, svn, mercurial, installation

A project that I am trying to use has a django import, so I am trying to install django.

In Windows.

I found directions on how to install it http://effbot.org/zone/django.htm#installing - and it requires a pull from an svn repository.

I have Mercurial hg installed - so I should not install svn - and https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion says that I can just use a command like

`svn co http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django`.

I am getting an error though, when I run it:

```
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What can I do then, to install django, on Windows, when I have on my system already installed python27, sqlite, and postgres, and Mercurial ?

Comment: Why does having Mercurial installed mean you can't install SVN? They're two different version control systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you pointed to is out of date. You do not need `svn` or `hg` to install Django. I would recommend reading the official installation docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/install/ and use a stable release rather than a checkout of the latest code.

Comment: I found how to use hg on a page from this main page, I had gone to a different one that only offered svn.

Answer (score 0):

`'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command` means `svn` is not installed or not found in your `SYSTEM PATH`.

Make sure `svn` or whatever tool that you are using is installed correctly and is in your system path, then continue with [django installation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/) .